# No se cual es mi problema, preciso explicaciones y consejos

Tags: funciones, dev-c++, booleano

No se bien cual es el problema que tuve, soy bastante nuevo así que ténganme paciencia, aparte que necesito consejos de como usar la variable bool, y si quieren de paso el void, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool Esprimo(int num);

int main () {
    int n;
    bool primo = true;
    cout << "Digite numero para comprobar si es primo: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    primo = Esprimo(n);
    if (primo == true) cout << "El numero es primo." << endl;
    else cout << "El numero no es primo." << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool Esprimo(int num) {
    for (int i = 2 ; 1 < num ; i++) 
        if (num % i == 0)
    return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: "No se bien cual es el problema que tuve" nosotros tampoco. Se claro con tu problema, este no es un sitio para depurar tu codigo, es para ayudarte con problemas puntuales. que error recibis? que hace? que no hace? que deberia hacer?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool primo = true;
bool Esprimo(int num);

int main () {
int n;

cout << "Digite numero para comprobar si es primo: " << endl;
cin >> n;
primo = Esprimo(n);
if (primo == true) cout << "El numero es primo." << endl;
else cout << "El numero no es primo." << endl;
return 0; 
}

bool Esprimo(int num) {
if (num == 0 || num == 1 || num == 4) return false;
    for (int x = 2; x < num / 2; x++) {
if (num % x == 0) return false;
}

return true;
}
```

He de suponer que esto es lo que quieres que haga tu código, te doy un consejo, aclara bien lo que quieras, no todos tenemos el tiempo para hacer tu tarea, este sitio web es para ayudar con consultas

Comment: Y como soluciona esto una pregunta que no aclara un problema, si no explica nada? ojo, aca no hacemos ejercicios, y no lo promovemos justamente para evitar que se siga reproduciendo. En este caso, supongo, resolviste un ejercicio que no era tuyo, y solo le sirve a quien pregunto (sobre todo, porque no tiene ni una explicacion ni del problema ni de la solucion)

Comment: Bueno man perdonen, me confunci, no puse la consigna del ejercicio, igualmente estaba respondida abajo del comentario original, gracias.